# How do I make a vector in data table that does sums on subsets based value range in another vector?

Tags: r, data.table, subset

What I am trying to do in R is to add a vector to the below data.table called RecentActivity, which makes a row-wise sum calculation of Activity, including only values for Activity in the sum where Week is not more than 2 weeks ago (by ID).

For example: If a certain ID is measured in week 2, I want RecentActivity to sum all the values for that ID where week equals 1 or 2. If measured in week 7, the sum needs to contain Activity values from week 6 and 7. In the first week, only week 1 needs to be included.

I would like an answer in data.table, because of its processing speed.

The is the data I want to add the RecentActivity vector to:

```
x <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,4), 
                Week = c(1,2,7,1,20,21,1,1,2,5,6), 
                Activity = c(5,2,3,1,0,4,3,8,2,5,3))
```

This is the desired output:

```
x <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,4), 
                Week = c(1,2,7,1,20,21,1,1,2,5,6), 
                Activity = c(5,2,3,1,0,4,3,8,2,5,3), 
                RecentActivity = c(5,7,3,1,0,4,3,8,10,5,8))
```

In the table, an ID occurs multiple times because it it measured in different weeks. Weeks can be skipped if nothing is measured. A row with Activity = 0 means the ID was measured but no Activity was found.

I guess of mine in using data.table:

```
x[, RecentActivity := sum(Activity[Week > (Week -2) & Week < (Week +1)]), by = c('ID')]
```

This does not lead to the desired result however.

Comment: Does `x[, c("dwn", "up") := .(Week - 2, Week + 1)] ; x[x, sum(Activity), on = .(ID, Week > dwn, Week < up), by = .EACHI]$V1` works for you? Some values doesn't seem to match

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thank you very much! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative way:

```
x[x[, .(ID, Week = Week + 1, Activity)],
  RecentActivity := Activity + i.Activity, on = c('ID','Week')]
x[is.na(RecentActivity), RecentActivity := Activity]
x

#     ID Week Activity RecentActivity
#  1:  1    1        5              5
#  2:  1    2        2              7
#  3:  1    7        3              3
#  4:  2    1        1              1
#  5:  2   20        0              0
#  6:  2   21        4              4
#  7:  3    1        3              3
#  8:  4    1        8              8
#  9:  4    2        2             10
# 10:  4    5        5              5
# 11:  4    6        3              8
```

As suggested by Frank, we can also set the default value for `RecentActivity` and then add the Activity of previous week:

```
x[, RecentActivity := Activity]
x[x[, .(ID, Week = Week + 1, Activity)],
  RecentActivity := RecentActivity + i.Activity, on = c('ID','Week')]
```

Comment: @Bas, it is not necessary to accept one answer if you prefer the elegant solution in comment by Arenburg.

Comment: Fwiw, David's comment-answer does not add a column to the table or something (?), instead making a new table, so I guess it's incomplete. Btw, you can do `DT[, v := default_value]; DT[mDT, on=, v := expr]` instead of assigning default value based on NAs afterwards, I guess.

Comment: @mt1022 Arenburg's answer was sufficient for me to figure out how to solve my problem, but Frank is right about your answer being more complete since it also adds the vector i wanted. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution constructing a new grouping variable:

```
x <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,4,4,4), 
                Week = c(1,2,7,1,20,21,1,1,2,5,6), 
                Activity = c(5,2,3,1,0,4,3,8,2,5,3))
x[, group:=cumsum((Week-shift(Week))>2 | is.na(shift(Week))), ID]
x[, RecentActivity:=cumsum(Activity), by=.(ID, group)][]
# > x[, RecentActivity:=cumsum(Activity), by=.(ID, group)][]
#     ID Week Activity group RecentActivity
#  1:  1    1        5     1              5
#  2:  1    2        2     1              7
#  3:  1    7        3     2              3
#  4:  2    1        1     1              1
#  5:  2   20        0     2              0
#  6:  2   21        4     2              4
#  7:  3    1        3     1              3
#  8:  4    1        8     1              8
#  9:  4    2        2     1             10
# 10:  4    5        5     2              5
# 11:  4    6        3     2              8
```

Or in one step:

```
x[, RecentActivity:=cumsum(Activity), by=.(ID, cumsum((Week-shift(Week))>2 | is.na(shift(Week))))][]
```